# Operator for change of state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry

I am trying to model a quantum system that has only three different classical states, so that the Hilbert space is simply $\mathbb C^3$, and let's call its standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$, with each of these vectors corresponding to one of the classical states of the system. Now, in my model, time is discrete, and there is a process (a sort of chemical reaction that occurs in one step with probability 1) that changes the state so that
$$e_1\to e_2, e_2\to e_2, e_3\to e_3.$$
Now, I'm tempted to say then that the change of state should in general look like
$$A(ae_1+be_2+ce_3)=(a+b)e_2+ce_3,$$
but then $A$ is not a unitary operator. Is this completely inadmissible, or is there a way to model it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit:** Maybe I need to use a statistical ensemble? Is that avoidable?

Comment: Your operator seems to be some kind of measurement, rather than an evolution operator...

Comment: Right, so that's exactly what I don't want, a measurement. The system stays isolated.